# php get value of array from key name

Tags: php, arrays, key-value

I have different array name with several names => values inside it.

in my file shortcode-config.php:

```
$shortcodes['video_section'] = array(
    'no_preview' => true,
    'params' => 'xxx',
    'shortcode' => '[sc1][/sc1]',
    'popup_title' => __('Video Section', THEME_NAME),
    'shortcode_icon' => __('li_video')
);

$shortcodes['image_section'] = array(
    'no_preview' => true,
    'params' => 'yyy',
    'shortcode' => '[sc2][/sc2]',
    'popup_title' => __('Image Section', THEME_NAME),
    'shortcode_icon' => __('li_image')
);
```

I want to get the value of `shortcode_icon`. I know the name of the array and I just want the value of a desired aray name.

For example I tried this without success:

```
define( 'TINYMCE_DIR', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) .'tinymce' );
require_once( TINYMCE_DIR . '/shortcodes-config.php' );

$name = 'video_section';
$icon = $shortcodes[$name]['shortcode_icon'];
```

Does I need to use a foreach loop or can I access to this just with name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access it via named indexes or in a loop. See examples below:

```
$name = 'video_section';
$icon = $shortcodes[$name]['shortcode_icon'];

var_dump($icon)
```

returns `string(8) "li_video"`

As $shortcodes is an array anyway, you can access any elements store in there using a loop, such as the video_section array and the image_selection array

```
foreach ($shortcodes as $code) {
    if ($code == "video_section") {
        //handle video section
    }
    if ($code == "image_section") {
        //handle video section
    }
}
```

**You also appear to be missing a semi colon at the end of the $name variable declaration.**

Turning on errors might be helpful:

`error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`

Alternatively write a function that passes a $name argument, just make sure the array is accessible in the function / outside of the scope:

```
$return = getShortcode('video_section');

function getShortcode($name)
{
    return $shortcodes[$name]['shortcode_icon'];
}
```

Comment: It was a function conflict when loading a php file inside a another function

Answer (score 0):

You can access it with both methods. First one with loop is used if you don't really now the exact name and where it is or if the array is dynamic. Second one if everything is static and you know the exact name and in which dimension it is.

So it works with

```
$name = 'video_section';
$icon = $shortcodes[$name]['shortcode_icon'];
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I can't make it work... These arrays comes from an other php file so I loaded with requiere_once but I can't get the value...

Comment: What do you get if you're doing `var_dump($icon);` (of course after you've assigned the variable)?

Comment: error occured [objet objet], I tried with hard coded value and I've got the same error...

Comment: That looks more like JavaScript output o.O

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yep, that's not from PHP.

Comment: @freaky Would you mind posting the full code in your question?

Comment: That 's normal it comes from my alert in ajax. But I've got nothing in my var in php...

Comment: Access the file directly, not with AJAX.

Comment: Why are we talking about AJAX? Remove that from the equation entirely. Debug your _PHP_, not some whole multi-layered web application. You can't possibly find your problem without divide and conquer. Basic debugging skill.

Comment: It not comes from my ajax script for sure. My var is empty. I think I've got a problem to acces to my php file where my arrays are stored...